# How to align the input fields?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="section-component">
  <h1>Contact Person</h1>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <label for="ex1">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="First name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The two input fields do not align in the same line when i take the label off the second field how can this be corrected ?

Comment: Might be better to simply add a `label` element with a "non-breaking space" to offset the space difference, *e.g:* `<label for="ex1">&nbsp;</label>`. You avoid negating, or trying to "win the race" against any framework styles in this way.

Comment: @Ashutosh Shrestha, See the 2nd answer, I have updated. But peoples are busy in down-voting.

Comment: @Swellar, See the 2nd answer, I have updated. But peoples are busy in down-voting.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, See the 2nd answer, I have updated. But peoples are busy in down-voting.

Answer (score 3):

Make the label as siblings of the `form-group` instead if you are planning to use only one label, and you can instead use `<span>` or any other element, because semantically speaking, `<label>` is not for this kind of naming, much like using `<h1>` in **Contact Person** instead of a `<label>` with style

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="section-component">
  <h1>Contact Person</h1>
  <label for="ex1">Name</label>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="First name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swellar has a good solution in his answer. However, if you are looking for an alternative, you can put a dummy `label` element and then set its CSS property as `visibility: hidden;`. So, you don't have to take out your `label` element from second field, and this label will be hidden.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="section-component">
  <h1>Contact Person</h1>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <label for="ex1">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="First name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <label for="ex1" style="visibility: hidden;">LName</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="section-component">
  <div class="col-xs-12"><h1>Contact Person</h1> </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
      <label for="ex1">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="First name" type="text">
    </div>
 </div> 
 
 
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
    <label for="ex2">Last Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="ex2" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
    </div>
 </div>   
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a `<label>` to your last name field.
You should always include a label for better accessibility.
If you don't want to use a label (which is not recommended), you can use flex-box to align it to the bottom:

```
.form-group: {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- website templates CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- custom  CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <!-- website templates  fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form>
     <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
            <label for="ex1" style="margin-bottom:0">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="First name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 form-field">
          <label></label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ex1" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
          </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>
 
</body>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  website template JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- custom date picker  JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/myScript1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: In case you didn't notice, OP removed the label from the second input because OP wants to use only one label, which is  **Name**